# Why doesn't `return $foo if /pattern/;` return $foo even though $foo matches pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using a tool that was published in a *Science* article but it is giving me a lot of trouble because I am not that familiar with Perl.

The code contains:

```
return $equa if /\@BOUNDARY/;
```

I believe that the code is supposed to return `$equa` if it contains the text `@BOUNDARY`, but it doesn't do that. Does the provided code have a mistake?

I am thinking of changing it to:

```
if ($equa =~ /\@BOUNDARY/) {
    return $equa;
}
```

Does this perform the same function?

---

For reference, the whole function in the original code is:

```
sub correctBoundaryReac {
    my $equa = shift;
    print $equa;
    return $equa if /\@BOUNDARY/;
    my( $left, $arrow, $right ) = ( '', '', '' );
    if( $equa =~ /^(<--|<==>|-->) (.+)/ ){
        $arrow = $1;
        $right = $2;
        $left = $right;
        $left =~ s/\@\S+/\@BOUNDARY/g;
    }
    elsif( $equa =~ /(.+) (<--|<==>|-->)$/ ){
        $left  = $1;
        $arrow = $2;
        $right = $left;
        $right =~ s/\@\S+/\@BOUNDARY/g;
    }
    else{
        die "Don't know how to fix bounadry reaction: $equa\n";
    }
    return "$left $arrow $right";
}
```

Comment: The `/$pattern/` applies the match to whatever is currently held in the default variable `$_`.  So what you are offering is _different_.  For example, `for (@arr)` has array elements in `$_` as it iterates over them.  This is just one example, `$_` is used a lot in Perl. Look over the previous code and see what could be held in `$_`.

Comment: In Perl most of the time the syntax sugar shortcuts are applied on $_ or @_ etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it has been explained, `if (/$pattern/)` means `if ($_ =~ /$pattern/`). See [General Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables). Then the question is – what is in `$_` in the code you show?

Many builtins and operators in Perl use `$_` as default. But *subroutines* don't use `$_` for anything, as far as I know. The `@_` gets the arguments, but it is a completely different variable.

However, inside of a sub the `$_` from the sub's enclosing scope is visible

```
use feature 'say';

sub show_it { say "I see: $_" }

for ('a'..'c') {
    show_it();    # prints with a through c
}
```

If this is intended in the code you show, it means that the sub checks for the pattern `'@BOUNDARY'` in the variable `$_` – but from the scope at which the sub is called. This is not good practice, to say the least, and can easily lead to subtle bugs. Any time the code in the calling scope is changed one has to review the subs but we aren't warned of that via sub's interface (the `$_` isn't a parameter). Besides, this isn't even needed since the calling code can check and condition the call on that.

I would rather believe that what you show is a simple bug, in which case it should be

```
return $equa if $equa =~ /\@BOUNDARY/;
```

This would mean that the sub first checks whether input has this already and if it does it just returns it. The rest of the shown code supports this -- it's all about that `'@BOUNDARY'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Perl-ism that is extremely unintuitive for those who aren't initiated into the arcane arts.

Perl has a so-called "hidden variable", `$_`. In essence, any function call with a single argument or comparison like this actually gets the value of `$_` substituted in place of the missing value. For instance,

```
foo() if /bar/;
```

is actually equivalent to

```
if ($_ =~ /bar/) {
    foo();
}
```

This makes intuitive sense if you think of a comparison operator as a function call, and the first example as having the missing argument I mentioned earlier.

In your case, what the code is doing is returning the value of some variable if the value of the `$_` variable matches the regex in question.

Comment: ***hidden variable*** is wrong. `$_` and others are called ***special variables*** or ***predefined variables***.

Comment: It's been called "the default variable". "Hidden variable" is a good name for it, I'm gonna start using that.

Answer (score 1):

```
return $equa if /\@BOUNDARY/;
```

is short for

```
return $equa if $_ =~ /\@BOUNDARY/;
```

so the conversion from an `if` statement modifier to an `if` statement results in

```
if (/\@BOUNDARY/) {
    return $equa;
}
```

or

```
if ($_ =~ /\@BOUNDARY/) {
    return $equa;
}
```

---

However, it's entirely likely that your current code is buggy. It apears that

```
return $equa if $equa =~ /\@BOUNDARY/;
```

should have been used, in which case it's perfectly fine to use

```
if ($equa =~ /\@BOUNDARY/) {
    return $equa;
}
```